# Windows 10: Force sign-out of user upon shutdown/restart

Tags: windows-10, user-accounts, fast-user-switching

I've got a Windows 10 Pro installation with two local users configured.

If I'm signed in to let's say "UserA" and I shutdown/restart the PC without explicitly signing out first and then sign in as "UserB" after boot-up, I can see that "UserA" still shows as "signed-in". This shows up on the user sub-menu of the Start menu.

Is there any way to change this behavior so that I'm always fully signed out upon restart/shutdown (perhaps with a GPO setting)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

Open Settings, Accounts, Sign-in Options.

[image: Sign-in Options]

Disable `Use my sign-in info to automatically finish setting up my device after an update or restart`

Hope that helps. Let's know.

Comment: I noticed you posted this exact answer on [this question](https://superuser.com/a/1262545/213131) as well. It would be better to vote to close one of these questions as a duplicate of the other instead of answering them both.

Answer (score 0):

Interactive logon: Don't display last signed-in

Location

Computer Configuration\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Local Policies\Security Options

This security policy setting determines whether the name of the last user to log on to the device is displayed on the Secure Desktop. If this policy is enabled, the full name of the last user to successfully log on is not displayed on the Secure Desktop, nor is the user’s logon tile displayed.

[image]

Comment: This is not the solution to my problem. The user is still signed in and this can be seen on the Start menu of the second user next to the name e.g. "UserA (signed-in)".