# Windows 10 - Users already logged in at boot

Tags: windows-10, user-accounts

Since the recent Fall Creators Update I'm facing a strange behavior while using Windows 10. My brother and I are using different accounts, both protected by password. When I turn on my PC and sign in, an automatic startup program (the [Blizzard Launcher](http://us.battle.net/en/app/)) warns me that it can't start since **another user on the same computer is using that app**. I thought that it was impossible, my brother's account can't be active if I just turned my PC on.

Actually, if I press the start button and the user icon, it says that my brother is signed in.

[image: Image for reference]

Ok, he must have turned the PC off without properly disconnecting the account, I thought, right?

So I let my brother log in his account, sign out, turn the PC off, turn it on again, log in my account. Same problem, his account is already signed in. Without even entering the password.

The same happens if he is the one to login first after booting, he sees me already signed in. If I switch account to mine, I can clearly see that **my startup programs are already started and ready**.

How is this possible? Windows is booting up accounts without even putting the password in?

Comment: The screenshot is not mine, I just took it from the web to better explain how I can tell for sure that my bro's account is already signed in

Comment: If you revert back to 1703 does the behavior continue to happen?

Comment: I wanted to be sure that this is a bug of the recent update before doing that, maybe it is some weird setting I didn't know about?

Comment: I was unable to reproduce the behavior on my 1709 VM.  I even created two users and enabled the built-in Administrator.

Comment: When you "turn it off", do you have hybrid shutdown (*Fast Startup*) enabled? Turn that off, if so, and try a full shutdown (e.g. *shutdown /s /t 0*). See https://lifehacker.com/enable-this-setting-to-make-windows-10-boot-up-faster-1743697169

Comment: I experience the exact same issue, just had it with EA Origin. For some reason Steam came up, although it can only be started once as well. I will have to try the proposed solution.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Open Settings, Accounts, Sign-in Options.

[image: Sign-in Options]

Disable `Use my sign-in info to automatically finish setting up my device after an update or restart`

Hope that helps. Let's know.

Comment: This can also be controlled by the `DisableAutomaticRestartSignOn` reg key in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System`. If you set it to 1, the option in Control Panel will no longer be visible.

Comment: This didn't work for me. I can still boot up my PC and see that other users are logged in, even though they shut down the PC

Comment: This worked, although it doesn't really make sense.  I was seeing the problem doing several logins, logouts, and restarts in a short period.  Windows 10 isn't doing updates every minute, so why is it auto signing in users on every single restart?

Comment: Typical Microsoft approach to security, just log people in without authentication. What could possibly go wrong?

Comment: @SamWatkins I am certainly not disagreeing with you, just adding a few details from Microsoft: _“After the final Windows Update reboot, the user will automatically be logged in via the Autologon mechanism, and the user's session is rehydrated with the persisted secrets. Additionally, the device is locked to protect the user's session. (…) Upon a successful ARSO configuration and login, the saved credentials are immediately deleted from disk.”_ https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-ds/manage/component-updates/winlogon-automatic-restart-sign-on--arso-

Answer (score 1):

You may also need to change the settings that turn shutting off into hibernate. Windows 10 will go to hibernation instead of shutdown even if you disabled it and asked to shutdown.

You can reach that setting by;

1. Go to Windows 10 Control Panel.
2. Go to the Hardware and Sound.
3. Go to Power Options.
4. Click "Choose what the power button does" on the left panel.
5. Click "Change settings that are currently unavailable" and type in the Admin password
6. Uncheck "Turn on fast startup (recommended)"

[image: Image provided by Shiraz]

Comment: I think this is the screen you're referring to:https://imgur.com/tv1FTD9

Comment: Fast boot is a different thing, unrelated to the automatic user logins. Also, there are no such items in Control Panel, did you translate the names from another language?

Comment: Yes, I translated from French.

Answer (score 0):

The account which got logged in automatically on my machine did not have any password set up.

I tried the [solution using Settings](https://superuser.com/a/1262545/84807) and by [editing the registry](https://superuser.com/questions/1262408/windows-10-users-already-logged-in-at-boot#comment1939386_1262545) without success.

The solution for me was to enable password login for that account. For details, see solution #1 on https://www.reneelab.com/windows-10-disable-auto-login.html.