# Windows 10 is signing in my two user accounts when I restart the computer

Tags: windows-10, user-accounts, windows-10-v1709

I recently upgraded my Windows 10 to the latest version: `1709`.

No probs - all went well.

Now, when I start the computer, it says both user accounts (dad and son) have auto signed in. This causes problems when some apps only work with one user signed in at one time (i.e. Overwatch).

How can I stop this from happening? Is there a setting I can please turn off?

Comment: In **Settings** -> **Accounts** -> **Sign-in options** the bottom section is **Privacy**, which has an auto-sign in option. If this is on for both accounts, set it off for the accounts you don't to log in.

Comment: @Mokubai - I'll make it an answer if the questioner confirms that it solves the problem. I can't easily test it, and the problem may lie elsehere.

Comment: Can confirm, both accounts had that setting turned *on*. I've turned it off for my son and restarted and it looks like his account is not auto signed in. I'll ask more questions when you add your comment as an answer :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Windows 10 - Users already logged in at boot](https://superuser.com/questions/1262408/windows-10-users-already-logged-in-at-boot)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you go to Windows 10 Settings (<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd>) and select **Accounts**, then at the bottom of **Sign-in options** you'll find the section labelled **Privacy**:

[image]

The last of the options here enables automatic sign-in: make sure that this is turned off for all accounts you don't want to sign in on restart.

Comment: in your picture, that *automatic sign-in* was turned *on* for both accounts. Reading the words, I _thought_ the auto sign-on only occurs/occurred when windows auto-restarts the system because of a _windows update requiring a restart_ .. vs ... a human manually restarting / shutting down then turning back on.

Comment: @Pure.Krome - I realised what the words imply, but it was the only account-based auto-sign-on I could find: I hoped it would answer the question, and it turns out that it does. That's why I wanted to check it solved the problem before I submitted an answer.

Comment: Kewl! I'm wondering if there's _something_ in some 'startup file' which windows keeps thinking we're still 'setting something up' after a reboot....  which windows isn't marking as completed. So it's stuck in this weird 'state'. /me shrugs