# Win10: the other local user automatically logs in when I am logged in

Tags: windows-10, user-accounts

I have Windows 10 Pro v.1709. I have two local accounts: mine and the one of my wife. Starting from the latest Windows 10 update, not every time but let's say 70% of times, when I log in with my local account, I discover that my wife account logged in too - of course that was not caused by my wife! I know that because if I click on my account image on Start, my wife's account is tagged with "Accesso effettuato" ("Access done", I guess in English).

The same of course happens when my wife logs in and then, instead of disconnecting, she simply clicks on my account to end her session, and then I log in.

[image]

Instead, this happens automatically, as there was a process that wakes up and logs in.

What can be done to fix this unwanted behaviour?

Comment: This answer worked for me: https://superuser.com/a/1262545/538801

Answer (score -1):

Might be a long shot, but have you tried disabling automatic login?

---

Disabling automatic login:

First open the run window with the windows key and the R key (WIN+R), then go ahead and type: `regedit` and hit ENTER.

You should now be greeted with a small menu on the left, and a large empty block on the right (a UAC prompt may of appeared - and if it didn't open, check if the UAC prompt is in the taskbar).

Now head into (navigate using the left bar):

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE > Software > Microsoft > Windows > CurrentVersion > Authentication > LogonUI > UserSwitch
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Authentication\LogonUI\UserSwitch`

On the right-hand side (the large box), double click the value `Enabled`, and go ahead and change it to `1`.

Now so it doesn't automatically set itself back to `0`, you want to right click `UserSwitch` on the left bar, head to permissions then click advanced.

Now click the button at the bottom of the new window that says `Disable Inheritance`.

Now at the top where it says `Owner: SYSTEM` click Change and type Administrators, then OK. If Administrators doesn't say `ALLOW` and `FULL CONTROL` leave a comment.

Double click/Edit on SYSTEM and set it to DENY, then click `Show Advanced` and Clear All. Then click the tick box for `Set Value`.

Hope I helped, and have a great day!